# ES2015:multikeys Map : where is the bottleneck?

Tags: javascript, optimization, maps, benchmarking

I have an algorithm coding issue in ES2017 with an async generator. I have to extract some data from a list of randomly-distributed maps.

My initial goal is to code a multi-keys, multiple values (a project I called mukemuva) data structure, with the ability of compacting the overlapping information.

(this is a long post, with some code reviews needed to answers it, so please take a while to answer...)

The problem I attempt to solve is the following:

- in a regular ES2015 Map, keys should be scalar values (0, 1, 2, 3, 'avc', true, ...) but not litteral property bags objects (such as 3D points { x:1, y:2, z: 3 } of functions; because JS  Maps use some internal hash of the JS engine, not the shape of the property bag itself.

For example, in the node REPL type

```
m = new Map()
m.set({ x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 } , 123)
m.set({ x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 } , 456)
m.set({ x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 } , 789)
```

... and you'll get a 3 pairs (key/value) resulting Map.

In a SQL RDBMS, doing the same will probably result in a  1 row table with just the ending value (789) and it is this behaviour that I expect.

## NAIVE IMPLEMENTATION

a fast, but memoty conuming implemetnation is the maintain an internal list of pairs:

```
const pairs = [
    { bag: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }, with_data: { r: 'ba', g: 'da', b: '55' } },
    { bag: { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 }, with_data: 123 }
]
```

and loop the whole list to determine how to fill the array:

- if a bag is present inside the list, replace its "with_data" value (UPDATE)
- if not, create a new entriy in the pairs list, with appropriate "bag" and "with_data" fileds (INSERT/CREATE)

This is super fast but can be troubled or messed up while the size of the entry list increases, especially for high numbers of entries (typically 500K to 1000K)

## ADVANCED IMPLEMENTATION

First I have conceptualized and named things :

```
m.set({ x: 1 y: 2, z: 3 }, 'c0ffee' )
```

- 'x', ''y  and z: 'z' are so called "roles"
- 1, 2, and 3 are called "role partitions" or "parts"
- the 'coffee' string is the stored "item"

### duck blocks

For the storage I have developped a blocks memoty pool allocator that stores data under pseudo random keys generated with a MWC (Multiply-With-Carry) genertor, such as :

```
pool.set(data) --> uid, a key 5 digits of 37 values each (0-9, _ and A-Z) 
pool.get(uid) --> arbitrary data, brought back to user
```

Using the pool, I can store duck blocks with this shape:

```
type DuckBlock = [
    uid: KEY37(5),
    ducktype: ROLE | PART | ITEM,
    counter: 0,      # refs counter
    related: array of KEY37(5),  # related block UIDs
    fellow: KEY37(5)  # "parent" block UID, for PART roles
    data: <any>    # user arbitrary data object
}
```

Using lookup Maps to store:

- roles: <role_name> => UID,
- parts: <part_value> => [UID] (lsit of parts)
- items

### querying ststem:

```
const generator = await multimap.select({ 
    x: 0,       // single value search
    y: '*'      // wildcard search,
    z: (val) => -5 < val && val < 5  // filter function search
})
```

Brief Algorithm:

- for each role, find the correponding partitions that martches filters
- for each part duck block, get the items UIDs
- carteian product parts_for_role_X * parts_for_role_Y * parts_for_role_Z
- get the item_uids list for each entry
- intersect the list s of items to get selecteed items
- grab the items by their UID

### insert / set up values

For the setting up of the value :

```
multimap.set({ x: 0, y:0, z: 0}, { rgb: 'bada55'})
```

... I compute the selection generator, with the values of the key as filters of ther select method, then :

- if empty: set anew value
- if not empty, overwrite the existing value

## THE QUESTION

the naive code is surprisingly fast (3s for 1M pointsrecorded) but I suspect dlete oprations to be costful (imagine an array.splice of a such array)

The advanced version could make a save of up to 25% space (tested) but it is sadly slow (almost 30 min for 1 M records)

I suspect the mechansim of collecting uids to have a too big algorithmic complexity...

But where is really the bootleneck and how could I proceed to fix it ?

(will have its own repo sooner...)
https://github.com/hefeust/data-manipulation-software/mukemuva

Thanks for replies.

Comment: Actual code-review is off-topic for SO; we have a whole separate site for it,  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.  The optimization part using the naive implementation as a starting point / reference implementation is on-topic for SO (at least I think so, I don't know JS very well so I didn't really read it), so you should edit this version of the question to focus on that.  Definitely don't say "code review" in the title, that's likely to make people ignore it.

Comment: If you do still want to ask for a code-review of the naive version, do that separately on codereview.SE.  (And make sure both questions link to each other if you don't delete this version, so people with thoughts about alternate implementations or an explanation of the observed performance can post them as answers here.)

Comment: OK... I wasn't aware of this way of doing things (sory...) so I will post on SE. THanks for notifying me !

Comment: just updated post title !;-)